# Angular 9 router events on lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am struggling with the Router.events observable given by Angular. My application has two lazy loaded module.
Each have a navmenu that display some links to navigate inside the application. I want one of my link to appear as selected depending on the current route.

The thing is that when I use the async pipe of an observable based on the router.events obserable, the routing events have already been emitted before my template is handled by angular.

I Kknow that if I subscribe manually inside the constructor of my component, I can get the data. If I do the same inside the ngOnInit function, same as with the async pipe, there are no data emitted.
It's working fine if I navigate using a link after the page is loaded.

Do you know a way on how I could achieve that ?

Thanks !

Comment: do you need to listen to event changes, or do you simply need to be able to obtain the current values? i.e. using ActivatedRoute will get you the current values without having to subcribe to all router events

Comment: Hi, well I need to listen to event changes since my component that displays links is built only once. Thanks

Comment: please provide the code you have for ngoninit and the subscribe so that the community can comment and if applicable

Comment: I someone needs it, this is how I fix it. If you have lazy loaded modules, make sure to import this service on the root component so the subscribe happens at the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I someone needs it, this is how I fix it. If you have lazy loaded modules, make sure to import this service on the root component so the subscribe happens at the very beginning.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs';
import {filter, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouterService {

  _events = new ReplaySubject<string>();

  constructor(private readonly router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(e => e as NavigationEnd),
      map((e: NavigationEnd) => e.urlAfterRedirects),
      tap((url) => this._events.next(url))
    ).subscribe();
  }

  get events(): Observable<string> {
    return this._events.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However, when I implemented mine, I just sent all the events instead of just one property (with no filtering either). I never know when I'm going to need something else in another spot. I'm just leaving my `RouterService` as an injectable replacement for `Router`. (Needed because of using lazily loaded modules.